# easylist and cleveref

Tags: cleveref, easylist

I'm trying to reference an item in an `easylist` using `cleveref`'s `\cref`. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[at, 5]{easylist}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{S1}
\begin{easylist}{enumerate}
@ This is a thing. \label{thing1}
@@ This is another thing.
@ stuff 2. \label{thing2}
\end{easylist}

Now I'm referring to \cref{thing1} (should be item 1) and \cref{thing2} (should be item 2), but item \ref{thing2} works.

\end{document}
```

When compiled, the `\cref` commands print `section 1`, the section counter, not the list counter. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Oh my, it seems that `easylist` breaks the reference. The counter information is wrong and `\label[enumi]{thing2}` does not help